# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/classes/library.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, properties-file

In my Spring application, I have a simple properties file located in folder `WEB-INF\classes` so that it, the `DispatcherServlet` and various other config files are in the `classpath`.

The props file is defined in the `DispatcherServlet` as:

```
<bean id="propertiesFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location">            
           <value>/WEB-INF/classes/library.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The `propertiesFactory` bean is injected into a controller:

```
@Autowired 
private Properties propertiesFactory;
```

And used in a one of the controller's methods as:

```
if (adminPassword.equals(propertiesFactory.getProperty("adminPassword"))) {
```

This all works perfectly, except for a test program as follows which has line:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("library-servlet.xml");
```

Which throws a `BeanCreationException`:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed
```

Because of:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/classes/library.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

But if the whole application can see the props file, why not this one program?

Comment: what is there in library-servlet.xml file...???

Comment: i am asking about content of library-servlet.xml

Comment: Much like any other `DispatcherServlet`, i.e. JavaBean registration, and all Spring and Hibernate configuration data. did you want to know something specifically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in `WEB-INF/classes` is added to the root of the classpath. As such, you need to refer to your resource simply as

```
library.properties
```

or better yet

```
classpath:library.properties
```

in

```
<property name="location">            
    <value>classpath:library.properties</value>
</property>
```

You may find it useful to run

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

and see what was used as classpath entries.