# Cloud java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF/logging.properties (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase

I tried to implement an Android App Using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible Environment with google cloud but when i try to deploy it to backend, it gives an exception.

> Cloud java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF/logging.properties (No
>   such file or directory)

In my WEB-INF directory this file exists. I also wrote the property name which exists above, in to the app engine-web.xml file but i still get the exception and can not deploy it. Can someone help ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What IDE are you using? Can you share the code so I can reproduce the issue. Also see if this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24598145/9015852

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.0. I am following this tutorial. https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible  Actually i didn't write any code, i just clone these 2 projects from tutorial and followed these steps. I will really appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of stuff in here.  First off, this is only applicable if you are using the [compat](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading#continuing_to_use_compat_runtimes) runtime on App Engine flexible.

The compat runtime for Java is configured similarly to the App Engine standard runtime for Java with `appengine-web.xml`.

In your `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` you should have the following lines:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
```

A typical `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/logging.properties` will look like:

```
# A default java.util.logging configuration.
# (All App Engine logging is through java.util.logging by default).
#
# To use this configuration, copy it into your application's WEB-INF
# folder and add the following to your appengine-web.xml:
#
# <system-properties>
#   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
# </system-properties>
#

# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = WARNING
```

Note - we encourage new users to avoid the compat runtime.  For logging on one of the other flexible runtimes for Java, you can use any logger that writes to either stdout or stderr and it will be picked up by Stackdriver Logging automatically or you can [add Stackdriver Logging to your logger](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-logging#add-a-stackdriver-logging-handler-to-a-logger).